# Getting data from 2 different tables from relational table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one called `Users` that has `id, name, last_name` and a table called `Messages` that has `id, user_id, message`.

I also have a relational table for user that follow other users `Follow`, in the form of `id, user_id, follower_user_id`

I need to get all the messages from the my user, lets say user 1 and all the messages from user 1 followers.

I have a query already but it is not returning the correct name on the current user.

How can i achieve this? Below is my initial query but it does not produce correct results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Messages.content, Messages.user_id, Users.name 
  FROM Follow JOIN Users ON Users.id = Follow.follower_user_id 
  JOIN Messages ON Messages.user_id = Follow.follower_user_id 
  OR Messages.user_id = Follow.user_id WHERE Follow.user_id = 1
```

Sample Data:

Messages:

```
id |  user_id   |  message
1  |      1     |  I am a message
2  |      3     |  Here is another message
3  |      2     |  Hello there
```

Users:

```
id |  name  | last_name
1  |  Test  | Last
2  |  Test2 | Last2
3  |  Test3 | Last3
```

Follow:

```
id  |  user_id  | follower_user_id
1   |     1     |   2
2   |     1     |   3
3   |     3     |   1
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT m.content, m.user_id, u.name 
FROM messages m JOIN
     users u
     ON m.user_id = u.id
WHERE m.user_id = 1 OR
      m.user_id IN (SELECT f.follower_user_id
                    FROM Follow f
                    WHERE f.user_id = 1
                   );
```

You should try to avoid `SELECT DISTINCT` unless it is necessary.

Also, the way your question is phrased, the user columns in `FOLLOW` could be in the wrong order (that is, it is possible that you want `f.follower_user_id = 1` in the subquery).